# API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR when using AWS_IAM authorizer for AWS::Serverless::Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am trying to set up a private API with a single lambda function using a sam template, but whatever I do the API gateway logs API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR. I have no idea what I do wrong. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html) isn't very specific about it. According to [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis-permissions.html) I think my template looks alright.

My code uses axios and aws4, I have also tried fetch instead of axios. I'm also getting the same error when I use Postman so I don't really think it is something wrong with my request. Everything works perfectly fine if I just disable the IAM authorization.

This is my template for the api and the lambda function I try to invoke.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  iam-api-example
Parameters:
  SamplePrivateApiStageName:
    Type: String
    Default: endpoint
  SampleTableName:
    Type: String
    Default: SampleTable
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Timeout: 10
    MemorySize: 128
    Handler: app.lambdaHandler
Resources:

  SamplePrivateApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: SamplePrivateApi
      StageName: !Ref SamplePrivateApiStageName
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt SamplePrivateApiAccessLogs.Arn
        Format: '{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","routeKey":"$context.routeKey", "path":"$context.path", "status":"$context.status","protocol":"$context.protocol", "responseLength":"$context.responseLength", "errorMessage":"$context.error.message", "responseType":"$context.error.responseType" }'
  SamplePrivateApiAccessLogs:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup

  GetQuestionFn:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      CodeUri: build/lambdas/private/advertisement/get-question
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref SampleTableName
      Events:
        GetQuestionFnEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /questions
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref SamplePrivateApi
            #Auth: 
              #Authorizer: "NONE"
```

If I stop using the defaultAuthorizer by uncommenting the last two auth-lines (i.e. using Authorizer: "NONE") in the lambda function everything works fine. So it only fails when I leave the defaultAuthorizer in charge.

The error I get in the API log is:

```
{
    "requestId": "12311ec0-732d-4088-a641-71f05e4bd418",
    "ip": "x.xx.xxx.xxx",
    "requestTime": "16/Jul/2021:12:37:01 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "routeKey": "-",
    "path": "/endpoint/questions",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "36",
    "errorMessage": "Internal server error",
    "responseType": "API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR"
}
```

In Postman, I use AWS signature authorization and the access key and secret key from an IAM user that has AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess policy. The regions should be correct as well.

[image]

My axios code I use in another lambda function (which also has AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess policy) currently looks like this.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
const aws4 = require('aws4')
const fetchQuestion = async () => {
  // Host is domain without https://
  const urlParts = QUESTION_API_DOMAIN.split('://')
  const host = urlParts.length > 1 ? urlParts[1] : ''

  if (!host) {
    console.error('No host could be extracted.')
    return null
  }

  const request = {
    host,
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${QUESTION_API_DOMAIN}/endpoint/questions`,
    path: `/endpoint/questions`,
  }

  const secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials?.secretAccessKey
  const accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials?.accessKeyId

  if (!secretAccessKey || !accessKeyId) {
    console.error('No credentials could be found.')
    return null
  }

  let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request, {
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials?.sessionToken,
  })

  // delete signedRequest.headers['Host']
  // delete signedRequest.headers['Content-Length']

  try {
    const response = await axios(signedRequest)
    return response.data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error while retrieving question:', err)
  }
}
```

No idea left what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API Gateway needs to have a role assigned to it which allows it to invoke the lambda function (authorizer)

Try using the `InvokeRole` property in the API Auth section (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html).

--- Updated ----

The invoke role arn must point to a role arn and not to a user see example below

````
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: SamplePrivateApi
      StageName: !Ref SamplePrivateApiStageName
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
        InvokeRole: !GetAtt APIGatewayRole.Arn
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt SamplePrivateApiAccessLogs.Arn
        Format: '{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","routeKey":"$context.routeKey", "path":"$context.path", "status":"$context.status","protocol":"$context.protocol", "responseLength":"$context.responseLength", "errorMessage":"$context.error.message", "responseType":"$context.error.responseType" }'
  SamplePrivateApiAccessLogs:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup


APIGatewayRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "authorizerLambdaInvokeAccess"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeAsync
                  - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Resource: !Sub ${AuthorizerLambdaFunction.Arn}

      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: "AllowApiGatewayServiceToAssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "apigateway.amazonaws.com" ```
````

Comment: Thanks, one step closer maybe, but something is still wrong. If I set InvokeRole to an arn of an IAM user that has the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole role I get an error of DEFAULT_5XX instead of the API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR. I also tried to add AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy to the lambda function that sends the axios request, together with the InvokeRole value CALLER_CREDENTIALS for the API, but that didn't work for some reason. In that case I still get the API_CONFIGURATION_ERROR error.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot :D That make sense. I replaced AuthorizerLambdaFunction with GetQuestionFn in you solution and it works for my case.